# Function to read line from standard input in C not working as expected

Tags: c, stdin

This function is supposed to get a line from the terminal. But it doesn't! I have gone over the code multiple times, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the problem! Please help! It doesn't seem that the code is entering the while block.

```
int getline(char line[]) {
int i = 0 ;
int c ; 
while( ((c=getchar()) != EOF) && (c =! '\n') ) { 
    line[i++] = c ;
}
line[i] = '\0' ; 
return i ; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is incorrect

```
while( ((c=getchar()) != EOF) && (c =! '\n') )
```

it should be

```
while( ((c=getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n') )
```

Do you notice the difference? `!=` is comparison (which is correct), and `=!` is completely different (which means negating `'\n'` and assign it to `c`) - which was wrong. So, attentions to the details please :)

Comment: mistakes like this do happen on bad days.. take it easy, and don't make it the 2nd time ..